# can a dot product of a permutation of $n$ $(1, -1) $ with a sequence of primes generate unique numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, arithmetic, prime-factorization

According to Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic any positive whole number is the product of primes. Therefore, I can create unique numbers by multiplying $n$ primes.

If I have a list of length $n$ generated by a finite sequence in the set ${1, -1}$, e.g., $(1, 1, -1, -1, 1, ...)$, and I do a dot product with a sequence of $n$ primes starting with 3, e.g., $(3, 5, 7, 11, 13, ...)$, do I have any guarantee that I will generate unique numbers by doing different permutations of 1s and -1s?

I know that I can't if my prime's sequence start with 2, $[1, 1, -1] \cdot [2, 3, 5] = [-1, -1, 1] \cdot [2, 3, 5]$, but I'm not sure for the cases where my sequence starts with higher primes.

Comment: Your problem is that $(-1)\times1 = 1 \times (-1)$ and $(-1)^2=1^2$. So no

Comment: What made you suspect that something like this might be true?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, I'm working on a ranking algorithm that creates those permutations of (1,-1), and I need to create unique numbers based on that. I thought that using prime numbers as I described would work. However, I realized that using a sequence o $2^x, 0 \le x \le n$ instead of primes works better for my purpose.

Comment: @adalrsjr1 A "permutation" usually means a shuffle of a given set. I think you would call something like $(1, 1, -1, 1)$ a (finite) sequence in the set $\{-1, 1\}$. Note that your new choice also won't work if you compare sequences of different length. $(1, 1, -1, 1)$ and $(1, 1, 1)$ give the same answer.

Comment: If you're only concerned about distinct sequences of the same length producing different sums, then I think you should be fine, though I haven't been able to prove it. The question is equivalent to asking if there is a sequence $a_0, \ldots, a_n$ in $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ such that $\sum_{k = 0} a_k 2^k = 0$.

Comment: Never mind, the proof of this fact is trivial. The sum will have the same sign as the last non-zero entry in the sequence, proving that such a sum cannot be $0$. In other words, your scheme works fine for generating numbers of a fixed length. Though, nb, you will not be able to reach all numbers between $2^{n + 1} - 1$ and $-2^{n + 1} - 1$ with sequences of length $n$. In fact, as an elementary counting argument shows, you will only get about half of them. Which half is an interesting question that might be worth exploring.

Comment: Thank you very much for all those extra comments @CharlesHudgins. In fact, all sequences are strict of the same size and I don't need to reach all numbers between $2^{n+1}-1$ and $-2^{n+1}-1$, I only need that they are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such guarantee. Some quick Python code shows that, for $[3,5,7,11,13]$ we have:
$$7=3(1)+5(-1)+7(1)+11(-1)+13(1)$$ and $$7=3(-1)+5(1)+7(1)+11(1)+13(-1)$$
This is enough to disprove your claim, but this is just one counter-example, I found many others with my code.

**Note:** This is the smallest list for which a counter-example is found. For smaller lists, your claim holds.